# Problem with quotes in "onclick" function

Tags: onclick, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate PHP variables into an "onclick" function.

Here is the line I'm having trouble with (look for the "onclick" part):

```
$imagecontent = '<div class="imagensfw" id="image'.$id.'" style="width:'.round($wd).'px;height:'.round($ht).'px;" onclick="viewimage(image'.$id.','.round($wd).','.$url.');"><p>Image</div>';
```

I'm particularly having trouble with concatenating the `$url` variable. I'd want to put it between quotes, but if I do so, the "onclick" function becomes all messed up (when the code is displayed in the browser).

I think that putting the URL address (`$url` variable as a parameter in the onclick) between quotes will fix the error its shooting:

> Error : missing ) after argument list

Here's my short Javascript function if you're interested:

```
function viewimage(id,width,url){
    var image = document.getElementById(id);
    image.innerHTML = '<img src="'+url+'" width="'+width+'" alt="Image" />';
}
```

Here's what I tried but didn't work (i.e. messed up the code):

```
onclick="viewimage(image'.$id.','.round($wd).', **"** '.$url.' **"** );"
```

(Noticed the double quotes added between the `$url` variable).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just a note (in case you didn't know, or it's useful) - you can escape double quotes (or other characters that Javascript uses) inside double quotes: "\"" gives "

Comment: Yes, I knew. But silly me, I just noticed an error on my part. I thought we could use double quotes in an "onclick" function. Turns out not, we have to use single quotes ( ' ). It fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, I just noticed an error on my part. I thought we could use double quotes in an "onclick" function. Turns out not, we have to use single quotes ( ' ). It fixed my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [variable parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)?  From the link's example:

```
$beer = 'Heineken';
echo "He drank some ${beer}s";
```

This should simplify the construction of your string.